# How to protect Rails associations (prevent override)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an object with a has_one relationship.  More specifically, here's the relationship:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :domain
end

class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

This is a pretty basic association.  However what I'm trying to figure out is some way of preventing the overriding of an association.

*Let's say I have a product that has a domain of "google.com" followed by a new product that attempts to save as "google.com".  I want the second one to fail.*

Any ideas on how to provide this association validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to perform the validation I was looking for, I had to add the following to the Domain model:

```
before_update :update_test

def update_test
   product_id_was.nil? || product_id.nil?
end
```

Comment: This suggests that perhaps your has_one and belongs_to association is backwards.  Here's a longer explanation: When you answered the suggestion below (about using validations), you said that "the associated field (domain) is still unique..."  But the has_one side of an association should not have a domain field.  Instead, the domain side would have a product_id (as acknowledged in your code above).  If you instead swapped the direction of the has_one/belongs_to association, you could use the normal validation methods.

Comment: @don thanks for the reply.  One note though, if you think about it: a domain belongs to a product.  Should I configure associations just because it gives me certain validations?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `validates <field>, uniqueness: true`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure this works.  The associated field (in this case :domain) is still unique, it's just having a new association.